# For which coverings by "geometrically nice" sets does the nerve admit "Vietoris-Rips-like" approximations?

Tags: computational-geometry, simplicial-stuff

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vietoris%E2%80%93Rips_complex&oldid=491420022#Relation_to_.C4.8Cech_complex) that the nerve (or Čech complex) of a covering by metric balls is nicely approximated by the Vietoris-Rips complex. Being a flag complex on its 1-simplices, the latter is computationally [much more tractable](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~afra/papers/smi10/vietoris.pdf) than the nerve itself.

Does anybody know of any other classes of "nice" coverings whose nerves have an approximation à la what Vietoris-Rips provides for coverings by balls? (I'm quite open to vague answers, heavy restrictions on the covers, and poor approximations.)